# Core Data - How to get related records through a join table

Tags: objective-c, core-data

Supposing you had a Core Data relationship such as:

```
Book ---->> Chapter ---->> Page
```

Given a `Book` object called `aBook`, `aBook.chapters` will return the book's chapters.  But how do you get a book's pages (i.e. `book.pages`)?  And how would you get the pages sorted by a `pageNumber` property?

Thank you!

Comment: It will help if you stop thinking of Core Data in terms of SQL. There are no join tables in Core Data. Core Data is an object graph management system. Entities are not tables. Properties are not columns and rows are not managed objects. If you think in objects, Core Data becomes much simpler to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Given a `Book` instance, `myBook`:

```
NSSet* pages = [myBook valueForKeyPath:@"chapters.@unionOfSets.pages"];
```

will give you the union of all pages. See the "[Set and Array Operators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE)" section in the Key-Value Coding Programming guide.

```
NSArray *chaperPages = [myBook.chapters valueForKeyPath:@"pages"];
```

will give you an array of `NSSet`s of pages, one set per chapter.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to get all `Page`s of a `Book` (`myBook`) sorted by `pageNumber` would be:

```
NSSet *pageSet = [myBook valueForKey:@"chapters.@unionOfSets.pages"];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey@"pageNumber" ascending:YES];
NSArray *pages = [pageSet sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
[sortDesc release];
```

This will yield an array with all pages from all chapters sorted by `pageNumber`